# What does it mean to add two subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering if you have two subspaces W1 and W2 of a vector space V, what is the precise definition W1 + W2? Another thing what do you end up with after you add the two subspaces? Is the resulting space also a subspace of V or not? I'm also hoping that you can provide a concrete example in which you actually show two subspaces being added.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Combining_Subspaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of $W_1 + W_2 $ is $\{w_1 + w_2 \colon w_1 \in W_1 ,\, w_2 \in W_2\}$, that is it is the set of all elements that is a sum of an element from $W_1$ and an element from $W_2$.

One can show (to work out the details could be a good training) that this is a subspace of $V$. In fact it is the smallest subspace that contains both $W_1$ and $W_2$. In other words it is the subspace generated by $W_1 \cup W_2$.

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ let $W_1= \{(t,t,0) \colon t \in \mathbb{R}\} $ and  $W_2= \{(s,0,s) \colon s \in \mathbb{R}\} $ then $W_1 + W_2 =  \{(s+t, t, s) \colon t,s \in \mathbb{R}\}$.